# Ways to show a system of polynomial equations has no solution

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, computational-geometry, groebner-bases

I came across the following system of polynomial equations on $X_1,\dots,X_{m-2}$:
$$
\begin{cases}
2X_{2s}+\sum\limits_{t=1}^{2s-1}(-1)^tX_tX_{2s-t}=0,\quad s=1,\dots,\frac{m}{2}-1,\\
X_sX_{m-s}+(-1)^s=0,\quad s=2,\dots,\frac{m}{2},\\
X_1X_{\frac{m}{2}}-2X_{\frac{m}{2}+1}=0,
\end{cases}
$$
where $m\ge10$ is an even integer.

By Groebner basis computation, I verified up to $m=20$ that $1$ is in the ideal generated by the above polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[X_1,\dots,X_{m-2}]$, whence the system has no solution in $\mathbb{C}^{m-2}$. Also, the number of equations is one more than the number of variables. Thus it is reasonable to conjecture that the system has no solution in $\mathbb{C}^{m-2}$ for any even $m\ge10$, and so **the question** arises naturally as how to prove this.

**Remark:** For a given value (not too lagre) of $m$, there are ways such as Groebner basis and various kinds of multipolynomial resultants to show that the system has no solution. But it seems to me that these algorithmic ways give not much insight for general $m$.

**A further question:** If we have known that the system has no solution in $\mathbb{C}^{m-2}$, we immediately deduce that it has no solution in $\mathbb{F}_p^{m-2}$ for all sufficiently large prime $p$. However, how can I then get a bound $N$ such that the system has no solution in $\mathbb{F}_p^{m-2}$ for prime $p>N$? I guess a bound like $p>m$ holds, but achieving this would be ad hoc to the equations.

Comment: In your first equation, do you mean $2X_{2s}$?

Comment: @B.Wellington The first equation is $2X_2-X_1^2=0$, so $X_2=\frac{X_1^2}{2}$. In fact, the first line of equations shows that $X_{2t}$ is a polynomial of $X_1,\dots,X_{2t-1}$ for $1\le t\le\frac{m}{2}-1$.

Comment: Call the variety $V(m)$. Have you tried looking for morphisms $V(m) \to V(d)$ for divisors $d$ of $m$? Maybe $m$ will have to be shifted to $m - 1$ or $(m - 1)/2$ or something. What's the story behind this variety? Sometimes that gives rise to natural morphisms.

Comment: @B.Wellington Thanks to your comment. I've changed $2X_{2t}$ to $2X_{2s}$ now.

Comment: For the "further question", even $p > m^2$ is likely way too optimistic.
One can easily write *linear* equations in $m$ variables, 
with no coefficient larger than $2$, that have no solution in $\bf C$ 
but do have a solution modulo some prime $p \sim 2^m$.  
(Use the binary expansion of $p$ to build up to $x_m=p$,
and then add the equation $x_m=0$.)

Comment: How did you "come across" this system?
The first line says that the generating polynomial
$P(t) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{m-2} X_k t^k$ satisfies
$P(t) P(-t) \equiv 1 \bmod t^m$, but the second line
doesn't look like any kind of standard polynomial property
(well, $P(t) P(-u)$ has an anti-diagonal of coefficients of $1$).
I suppose you know already that there's an action of a cyclic group $C$ 
of order $m$: for each $m$-th root of unity $\zeta$ you can
multiply each $X_k$ by $\zeta^k$.  Plus $X_{m/2} = \pm 1$ or $\pm i$
according as $m/2$ is odd or even, with the two sign choices
equivalent under $C$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I came across this system in a study for power residue difference set. I found that if the subgroup of index $m$ in $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ form a difference set of $\mathbb{F}_p^+$, then $X_r\equiv\Gamma_p(\frac{r}{m})\equiv\frac{1}{(r(p-1)/m)!}\pmod{p}$ should satisty the first line of equations. The last two lines of equations come from the own properties of $p$-adic Gamma functions (here I'm considering the case when $2$ is a $m$-th power in $\mathbb{F}_p$). My origional purpose is to exclude the existence of certain power residue difference sets by showing it has no solutions.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Besides your observation, there is also a change of variables of the form $X_r=\pm\zeta^rY_r$ to kill the powers of -1 in the first two lines simultaneously; here $\zeta$ is a $m/2$ or $2m$-th root of unity according to $4$ divides $m$ or not.

Answer (score 4):

For the **Further question,** See [Pascal Koiran's paper](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5188175/koiranrev.pdf) (which, I believe, is the last word in the subject, even if almost 20 years old).

Comment: For a given $m$, provided we have know that the system has no solution over $\mathbb{C}$, this paper says that the number of primes $p$ such that the system has solution over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is bounded. But does this provide a concrete bound $N$ such that the system has no solution whenever $p>N$?